# How to remove unused config node(s) from nodered

Tags: node-red

**Issue**

Dangling config nodes in node red as it is not obvious from the documentation.

**Question**

How to remove unused config node(s)?

Answer (score 5):

To delete one or more unused nodes, you can filter on `unused` nodes in the config tab. Click the node and press the delete key.

**To Delete All Unused**
Click a node in the configuration tab, press (ctrl-a) to select them all, and press delete

[image]

Comment: You can also double click on each one to open its edit dialog, and click the delete button there.